# View file contents on a Salt Stack minion

Tags: cat, saltstack

How do I output the contents of a file on all my minions using Salt Stack?

The only 'pull' functionality I can find is in [this minion push commit](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/110b73c2b16583982c59c5fac83f1f7273b1b1f8), but this requires configuration changes on the master.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution using `cmd.run` module:

```
salt '*' cmd.run 'cat /path/to/file'
```

Comment: This will only work if the file is small enough, otherwise you'll get "no response" timeouts.

Answer (score 10):

Get the contents of a file without using external commands:

```
sudo salt '*' cp.get_file_str file:///etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added on a later version of Salt, you can find it in the salt official documentation on this [link](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push).

You can push a file from a salt minion to the master by issuing this command:

```
salt '*' cp.push /path/to/file
```

Keep in mind that you need to enable it on the salt master configuration file before by setting the `file_recv` option to `True`

Comment: where does the file end up?

Comment: By default, the file ends up under /var/cache/salt/master/minions/minion-id/files
But it's also possible to set it with the upload_path='/new/path/fstab' option.